# makefile error "error checking context: 'no permission to read from" when file is not readable

Tags: make, gnu-make

I'm running into an error of:

```
make deploy_test
error checking context: 'no permission to read from '.../ssh-priv-key''.
make: *** [Makefile:24: build_deploy] Error 1
```

This ssh-priv-key file is intentionally non readable to the user. How can I avoid this permission issue stopping the makefile from running as intended?

I've not been able to find anything on a web search and can't find anything relevant in `man make` either. I'm using GNU Make.

Comment: Are you asking how to ignore [Errors in Recipes](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-_002d-_0028in-recipes_0029) ?